# input type="email"

Tags: html5, forms

I have a form where I ask for email addresses.  Usually I'd use

```
<input type="email" ...>
```

but I want to allow a user to type `foo` rather than `foo@mycompany.com` in the (likely) case that they are using an `@mycompany.com` email address.  Is there a way to get around the validation (if format matches this regex, accept; otherwise, validate normally), or should I just use

```
<input type="text" ...>
```

and ignore the semantics and so forth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to allow content that isn't in a [valid email address forma](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)t then you'll want to use `<input type="text" ...>` like you said. Although someone *may* enter a whole email address, it isn't exclusive to that field so using `<input type="email" ...>` would not be appropriate.

You can also turn off form validation if you don't want the browser to validate those fields for you. But that kind of defeats the purpose of using HTML5 features.

Comment: Sounds good, just making sure I'm doing the right thing.

Comment: Wait... what do you think about having the form autocomplete the email address and using type="email"?

Comment: In that case I would use `<input type="email" ...>` since the final content of that field will be a valid email address.

Comment: OK, it's coded and working nicely.  If they have Javascript turned off but have an HTML5 browser they'll have to complete the email on their own, but that's really not too bad of a corner case.

Answer (score 2):

[HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html) allows `pattern=""` attribute to be [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html#input.email.attrs.pattern) :

> Specifies a regular expression against
>   which a UA is meant to check the value
>   of the control represented by its
>   element.
>
> A regular expression that must match
>   the JavaScript Pattern production as
>   specified in [ECMA 262].

**Examples:**

```
<input type="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" value="">

<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$">
```

But I would use `type="text"` to be on a safer side -- in this case you can validate ANY user input.

Comment: -1 for providing a regex that rejects valid email addresses - http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585 - http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: @dmsnell This example was taken from a webpage and not written by myself. I'm guilty for not checking it... but, on another had, this question is not about "how to _properly_ validate email address on client side". In general, not to use pattern at all will be a better idea (why duplicate the functionality (pattern) if it is already provided by browser), unless there are specific requirements.

Comment: @dmsnell: OF course the general RFC 5322 specification is not even regular, so a true regular expression can never parse it.  It's at least Dyck-complete, so even backreferences aren't enough (though I think there's a Perl construct that would allow such parsing).  So any `pattern` will have to either accept an invalid email address or reject a valid one.

Comment: @LazyOne: I know this question isn't about how to *properly* validate email addresses, but my comment was about *improperly rejecting* valid input.  The given pattern would have even rejected some valid @mycompany.com email addresses.  It's pretty frustrating to enter your email address on a form and have it come back and tell you that it's invalid.

Comment: @dmsnell I absolutely agree with you. When I started to work at my current job they gave me very short email address (it supposed to be temporal address, but I was using it for nearly 2 years) -- `a@mycompany.com` (yep, just one letter before @). When I tried to register on some sites (forums, product support etc) it was rejected as invalid quite few times. In the end, they created me an alias (like `andriy@mycompany.com`) so I could use it instead. I'm still using both of them -- depending on situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new HTML5 [pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#form.data.pattern) attribute to specify valid formats for an input field using a JavaScript regexp, then put the error message in the `title` attribute:

```
<input type="email" pattern="([regexp])" title="Your error message" />
```

However, in the scenario you describe, there's not much advantage of doing it this way over using `type="text"` except for the fact that Mobile Safari users will see an email keyboard instead of the full qwerty one.

As such, you might consider making it a requirement to use a company address, appending that in plain text after the text field, and prompting users for the first part of the email address rather than the full version.

Comment: `pattern` is ignored in Firefox with `type="email"` in my tests.

Comment: @Charles Best to use `type="text"` then, or simply require that they type their full email address including your company domain; the latter is what I'd do.

Comment: At the moment I've made it `type="email"` and added a bit of JavaScript to complete email addresses that (otherwise) look like mycompany email addresses.  But thanks for the input, you have my +1 already.